# How to set the row width of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to be able to see all the text in a row.

I was able to change the column height using `table.setRowHeight` .. but it does not help.

How do I change the column width?

[image]

```
public MutationTable(JFrame window,IVirus[] data) {
    super(window, "Edit Mutation ",true);
    MutationModel model = new MutationModel(data);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    String row[]= {"British Variant", "Chinese Variant", "SouthAfrican Variant"};
    RowedTableScroll jt_rowed =new RowedTableScroll(table,row);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize()));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    this.add(new RowedTableScroll(table,row));
    this.getPreferredSize();
    setBounds(390,170,200,300);

    this.pack();
}
```

Comment: "RowedTableScroll" is not a JDK class. We don't know what it does, so we can't help. Read the API of the class or look at the source code to see how the width of that component is set.

Comment: Sans an MRE / SSCCE, the best I can do is: possibly something like `TableColumn tableColumn = jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1); tableColumn.setMinWidth(300);` **General Tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) Don't extend components, containers or windows without good reason.